# Rails: Twitter Omniauth gem 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter omniauth gem in my web application.  I stored my key and secret in my DB.

This is my middleware code

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

 provider :twitter, lambda { Site.config[:twitter][:key] },lambda{ Site.config[:twitter][:secret] }

 end
```

This returns unauthorized error.

But when i specify my key and secret directly in the middleware it works.

(i.e)

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

 provider :twitter, "consumer_key" , "consumer_secret"

 end
```

What is wrong with my first approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Setup Phase](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase)

```
provider :twitter, :setup => true
```

And then in controller:

```
def setup
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = Site.config[:twitter][:key]
  request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = Site.config[:twitter][:secret]
  render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

Routes:

```
match '/auth/:provider/setup' => 'sessions#setup' # for example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your consumer_key and consumer secret in the development.rb and production.rb

```
# twitter api credential
  config.twitt_consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.twitt_consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

And then you can use it

```
provider :twitter, Rails.application.config.twitt_consumer_key, Rails.application.config.twitt_consumer_secret
```